# Expression Tree printing

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, expression-trees

I'm working on an expression tree project at the moment that takes in a postfix expression from the user(i.e, 7 8 +) and stores it in an expression tree; the program should then print the tree in a typical tree format and present the user with the option to print out an infix, prefix, or postfix format.

As of now, it seems my tree is being properly instantiated, but every time I try to print it the format is slightly off and each operator/operand is duplicated. So, if the output should look like

```
       -
    6    5
```

it ends up looking like

```
       - -

  6 5 6 5
```

On top of that, whenever I try to print out an infix/prefix/postfix format, I run into several null pointer exceptions - and the way I wrote the code, I don't know how that is even possible.

The main method for printing out the tree is as follows:

```
public String toString()    {
    String result = "";
    int printDepth = getHeight();
    int possibleNodes = (int)Math.pow(2, printDepth+1);
    int countNodes = 0;

    UnorderedListADT<BTNode<ExpressionTreeNode>> nodes = new UnorderedList<BTNode<ExpressionTreeNode>>();
    UnorderedListADT<Integer> levelList = new UnorderedList<Integer>();
    BTNode<ExpressionTreeNode> current;

    nodes.addToRear(root);
    Integer currentLevel = 0;
    Integer previousLevel = -1;
    levelList.addToRear(currentLevel);

    while(countNodes < possibleNodes)   {
        countNodes += 1;
        current = nodes.removeFirst();
        currentLevel = levelList.removeFirst();

        if(currentLevel>previousLevel)  {
            result += "\n\n";
            previousLevel = currentLevel;
            for(int a=0;a<((Math.pow(2, (printDepth-currentLevel+1))-1));a++)   {
                result += " ";
            }
        }
        if(current!=null)   {
            result += (current.getElement()).toString()+" ";
            nodes.addToRear(current.getLeft());
            levelList.addToRear(currentLevel+1);
            nodes.addToRear(current.getRight());
            levelList.addToRear(currentLevel+1);
        }
        else    {
            nodes.addToRear(null);
            levelList.addToRear(currentLevel+1);
            nodes.addToRear(null);
            levelList.addToRear(currentLevel+1);
            result += " ";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and the method for printing out the tree in various other formats...

```
public String printInorder()    {
        String result = "";
        if(getLeft()!=null)
            getLeft().printInorder();

        result+= root.getElement()+" ";

        if(getRight()!=null)//one null pointer occurs here
            getRight().printInorder();//another occurs here

        return result;
    }
```

The methods for preorder and postorder are pretty much the same, they just change the order of result+=root.getElement()+" ";

I've tried reformatting these methods in all sorts of ways, but every time I just end up getting the same errors. I know that the entire tree isn't null, but what am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is pretty hairy to eyeball.  Have you tried walking through this with a debugger?

Comment: In all honesty, even I'm not sure how this method is supposed to work - it was provided to us by our professor, and when I couldn't even mentally fathom how to make a method like this, I just copied it into my program word for word.

Comment: I still think running this with (initially) simple inputs and a debugger, walking through it a step at a time is the way to get information.  From there we might be able to offer better advice/solutions.